# Mocha-web client-side tests not running with Velocity for Meteor application

Tags: meteor, mocha.js, velocity

I have 2 samples Mocha web tests which I'm trying to run using Velocity.

For some reason, client-side tests under the /tests/mocha/client folder are never executed, whereas the server side tests under the /tests/mocha/server folder run fine.

Here is the structure of my project todos (meteor example project)

- client
- lib
- packages
- server
- tests

  - mocha

    - client
    - server

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and it was related to having the browser-policy package installed.

What you need to do is look in the JavaScript console, e.g. in Chrome developer tools, look at the console tab. (Apple Key + option key + I). You should see errors like this:

> Refused to frame '`http://localhost:5000/?mocha=true`' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src
>   'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so
>   'default-src' is used as a fallback.

You should still have this package installed for security purposes, but for a test do the following:

```
meteor remove browser-policy
meteor
```

I would guess that you see your client tests running now? In my case I saw them as soon as I removed the browser-policy package. Basically what you need to do at this point is to tweak your browser policy settings for your application to allow the iframe for mocha, e.g. `http://localhost:5000`, but only for the development environment.

Before changing the code put back the browser-policy package.

```
meteor add browser-policy
```

Now make the changes to your browser policy settings:

```
  // Your browser policy settings, e.g.
  // BrowserPolicy.content...

  // Need to run this at the end so that it overrides normal broswer policy settings.
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development")
  {
    console.log("In development mode. Allowing all framing so that mocha-web can run for tests.");
    this.BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll("localhost:*");
    this.BrowserPolicy.content.allowConnectOrigin("ws://localhost:5000");
    this.BrowserPolicy.content.allowConnectOrigin("ws://localhost:3000");
  }
```

Comment: Where are the browser policy settings stored?

Comment: You just configure it in a script that is used on the server only. See the package for more information, https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/browser-policy